Issues with SQLAlchemy
I'm trying to run the following code (some of the stuff I blind, like the passwords)to get some Snowflake data into a Jupyter notebook:
import math as math
import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import seaborn as sns;
import snowflake
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL;

url = URL(account = 'x'
          ,user = 'anthony.j@email.com'
          ,database = 'x' 
          ,warehouse= 'x'
          ,password= 'xx'
          ,role = 'x');

HL_Aud_tseries= "select * from RAW.WORKSPACE__ANALYST.TSP_FILE_HL_AUD_CORR_TEST_JAJ;"
engine = create_engine(url);
con = engine.connect();

with engine.connect() as conn:
    HL_AUD = pd.read_sql(
        sql=HL_Aud_tseries,
        con=conn.connection
    )

This gives me the following error:
/var/folders/mv/kmklxh114b136cc_j8d65vl00000gn/T/ipykernel_78417/3931250517.py:3: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
HL_AUD = pd.read_sql(
I thought I was using SQLAlchemy!!!! Please advise and thanks in advance!

Omit the with block and just use HL_AUD = pd.read_sql_query(sql=HL_Aud_tseries, con=engine)

The semicolons aren't needed in Python.

I have been frustrated with the same warning; but note that it is NOT an "error".
